# Deploy Node.js on OpenShift

Tags: node.js, server, openshift

I'm trying to deploy my node.js app on OpenShift 3 starter. The deployment is active and no errors are reported. But When I am trying to access the site, "Application is not available" shows. A similar issue occured when I was trying to deploy it on heroku.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var mainCtrl = require('./controllers/mainCtrl');

var session = require('client-sessions');

//set up template engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/public/views');

//middleware
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/assets'));
app.use(session({
  cookieName: 'session',
  secret: 'jfsa6a5sef6wea4f535641fds53s3das12d',
  duration: 180 * 60 * 1000,
  activeDuration: 180  * 60 * 1000,
  http: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
}));

//database
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
//connect to database
var database = 'mongodb://test:test@ds153400.mlab.com:53400/open_comments';
mongoose.connect(database);
//create a schema
const commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  http: String,
  domain: String,
  account: String,
  content: {
    user: String,
    date: Date,
    comment: String,
    votes: Number
  }
});
const accountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  account: {type: String, unique: true},
  user: String,
  email: {type: String, unique: true},
  password: String,
  history: [],
  bookmarks: [],
  notifications: []
});

//create a model
//for comments
var Comments = mongoose.model('Comments', commentSchema);
//for account info
var Account = mongoose.model('Account', accountSchema);


//for https
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};

mainCtrl(app, Comments, Account);


// Create an HTTPS service identical to the HTTP service.
https.createServer(options, app).listen(process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080);
```

The server is working well locally. One issue that I can come up with is that by default, openshift is using http rather than https. But I only offered port for https since only one listen is allowed.

**Update:**
I deleted https server and rebuilt it. It is working now. I have no idea what happened but thank you, Graham Dumpleton!

Comment: Of you use ``oc rsh`` to access the pod, or a terminal in the web console, can you do both ``curl https://localhost:8080`` and ``curl https://$HOSTNAME:8080`` and get a correct response?

Comment: As to HTTP/HTTPS, if you are going to terminate TLS connections yourself, using your own custom domain name certificate, you have to specify pass through for the route. If you are just using a self signed certificate, let OpenShift handle TLS connection termination by specifying a secure route when creating the route. Have your application just accept HTTP requests. OpenShift will then accept HTTPS and proxy to your application as HTTP.